# Assistance with Celery Logging

Tags: python, logging, celery

So Celery is a super great library but its documentation for the logging section isn't the best, which bring me here to request for assistance.

My Script as of now is as so (well in summary):

```
import logging
from celery import Celery
from celery.utils.log import get_logger
from task import process
import config

logger = get_logger(__name__)
timber_handler = timber.TimberHandler(api_key=config.key,
                                  level=logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(timber_handler)



app = Celery('task',
             broker=config.url,
             backend='rpc://')

@app.task
def run_task():
    status = get_status() # get alive or dead status
    if status == 1:
        logger.info("Task is running")
        process()


@app.on_after_configure.connect
def task_periodic(**kwargs):
    app.add_periodic_task(2.0, run_task.s(), name="Run Constantly")
    # More tasks
```

The process function in the tasks.py file is very basic function hitting up APIs and DBs for some info and I want to be able to log that to a logger (timber.io) which attaches to the python logging library and is an online storage for logs.

However, my major issue is that the logs are getting sent to stdout and not to the timber logs. I have looked at celery.signals but the documentation isn't great. Any assistance here would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
import logging
import os
import sys
from celery import Celery
from celery.signals import after_setup_logger

app = Celery('app')
app.conf.update({
    'broker_url': 'filesystem://',
    'broker_transport_options': {
        'data_folder_in': './broker/out',
        'data_folder_out': './broker/out',
        'data_folder_processed': './broker/processed'
    },
    'result_persistent': False,
    'task_serializer': 'json',
    'result_serializer': 'json',
    'accept_content': ['json']})


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


for f in ['./broker/out', './broker/processed']:
    if not os.path.exists(f):
        os.makedirs(f)

@after_setup_logger.connect
def setup_loggers(logger, *args, **kwargs):
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

    # add filehandler
    fh = logging.FileHandler('logs.log')
    fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(fh)


@app.task()
def add(x, y):
    logger.info('Found addition')
    logger.info('Added {0} and {1} to result, '.format(x,y))
    return x+y


if __name__ == '__main__':
    task = add.s(x=2, y=3).delay()
```

Start the worker like this:

```
celery worker --app=app.app --concurrency=1 --loglevel=INFO
```

And kick off the task asynchronously:

```
python app.py
```

I've changed it so it's a stand-alone script that just uses the filesystem as a message broker (also, I've deliberately replaced the timber.io handler with a filehandler).

This writes the logs to `logs.log` (replace the filehandler with the timber.io handler and that should solve your issue).

I had a bit of a hard time as the I couldn't get it working with `worker_hijack_root_logger=False` and a custom logger defined in `setup_logging`.

However, after revisiting the docs, I came to the conclusion it's a better option to not override the logger but just augment it:

> If you’d like to augment the logging configuration setup by Celery
>   then you can use the after_setup_logger and after_setup_task_logger
>   signals.

See also: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html#after-setup-logger

Comment: Certainly, I just have a quick question. How may I pass that logger to the run_task() method?

Comment: You don't need to. What you do for your tasks, is this:

     `from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
     logger = get_task_logger(__name__)`

and then use `logger` in your task

Comment: I just what I wrote to test but Im not getting logs, did I do something incorrectly? Also, Timber.io is very new and might not support celery loggers which could be a possible scenario