# How to save celery task stdout \ stderr to the text files?

Tags: python, celery

I use celery tasks with external modules that send information with print() to stdout. How to save all prints of celery task to predefined file? Ideally, if each task has its own separate file.

Example `main.py` for running **redis** on `localhost:6379`:

```
import time

from celery import Celery

def long_run_func():
    print('>>> Start running long_run_func()')
    time.sleep(5)
    print('>>> End running long_run_func()')

celery = Celery('celery_task', broker='redis://localhost:6379')

@celery.task(name="long_run_celery_task")
def long_run_celery_task():
    long_run_func()

long_run_celery_task.delay()
```

Now run Celery worker:

```
celery -A main:celery worker --loglevel=INFO
```

And if you will run `main.py` you can see in celery lines from long_run_func() prints:

```
[2024-01-11 17:30:52,746: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] >>> Start running long_run_func()
[2024-01-11 17:30:57,751: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] >>> End running long_run_func()
```

It possible to setup `@celery.task` to dump all this logs to some string var or file? I mean, if I have several such tasks and they run at the same time, then be able to separate these outputs depending on the task, and not mix everything into a single log.

Comment: you need add a MRE.

Comment: @leaf_yakitori can you explain please what is MRE?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Can't you just redirect the output to  file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52094938/10787867

Answer (score 1):

1. > It possible to setup @celery.task to dump all this logs to some string var or file?

- you can use `-f --logfile` command option to dump all logs
  to the file you want.
- example:

```
command:
celery -A main:celery worker --loglevel=INFO -f test.log

test.log:
[2024-01-13 09:56:04,119: INFO/MainProcess] Task long_run_celery_task[bae57432-18de-4f00-8227-cdf34856cd15] received
[2024-01-13 09:56:04,121: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] >>> Start running long_run_func()
[2024-01-13 09:56:09,123: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] >>> End running long_run_func()
[2024-01-13 09:56:09,127: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] Task long_run_celery_task[bae57432-18de-4f00-8227-cdf34856cd15] succeeded in 5.006108791014412s: None
```

- advice:

  - when you need use a new command but don't know how to use it, you can try `--help`, such as `celery --help`
  - or you can check the doc of it, such as http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#logging

---

2. > if I have several such tasks and they run at the same time, then be able to separate these outputs depending on the task, and not mix everything into a single log.

#### simple but dirty way

- if you only have some tasks to run, just write some python file and than run them in different command.
- example:

```
celery -A main1:celery worker --loglevel=INFO -f test1.log
celery -A main2:celery worker --loglevel=INFO -f test2.log
celery -A main3:celery worker --loglevel=INFO -f test3.log
```

---

#### better way

- set `logger` by name and set `handler`
- example:

```
import time
import logging
import os
from celery import Celery

def long_run_func():
    l = custom_logger("long")
    l.info('>>> Start running long_run_func()')
    time.sleep(5)
    l.info('>>> End running long_run_func()')

def short_run_func():
    l = custom_logger("short")
    l.info('>>> Start running short_run_func()')
    time.sleep(3)
    l.info('>>> End running short_run_func()')

celery = Celery(__name__,broker='redis://localhost:6379')

@celery.task(name="long_run_celery_task")
def long_run_celery_task():
    long_run_func()

@celery.task(name="short_run_celery_task")
def short_run_celery_task():
    short_run_func()

def custom_logger(name):
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    handler = logging.FileHandler(os.path.join(name + '.log'), 'w')
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    return logger

long_run_celery_task.delay()
short_run_celery_task.delay()
```

- result:

```
long.log
>>> Start running long_run_func()
>>> End running long_run_func()
short.log
>>> Start running short_run_func()
>>> End running short_run_func()
```

- if you want to use the same format as `print`, you can use：

```
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s') #custom formatter
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is writing a logger class and redirecting the std out and error file descriptors to that class. I am using pandas lib for time so I recommend it.
code as follows ->

```
import sys
import pandas as pd

class Logger:
    def __init__(self, pipe, suffix: str, interval: str):
        self.terminal = pipe
        self.file_suffix = suffix
        self.interval = interval
        self.log_time = pd.Timestamp.now().floor(self.interval)
        self.log_file = open(self.log_time.__str__() + self.file_suffix, "a")

    def write(self, message):
        self.terminal.write(message)
        self.terminal.flush()
        if pd.Timestamp.now().floor(self.interval) > self.log_time:
            self.log_time = pd.Timestamp.now().floor(self.interval)
            self.log_file = open(self.log_time.__str__() + self.file_suffix, "a")
            self.log_file.write(message)
            self.log_file.flush()
        else:
            self.log_file.write(message)
            self.log_file.flush()

    def flush(self):
        pass


sys.stdout = Logger(sys.stdout, "_system_stdout.log", "15min")
sys.stderr = Logger(sys.stderr, "_system_stderr.log", "15min")

print("test")
```